# Is computer science really a branch or sub-branch of physics?

Tags: physics

Given that a computer is basically an electronic machine, is computer science really a branch of electronics, which is in turn a branch of physics?

Comment: Given that physics is the study of how the universe works, and everything we study is in the universe, ...

Comment: Whether a field is a branch of something else is very poorly defined in general and seems to be mostly a matter of opinion and is also a question _about_ computer science, but not _of_ computer science. This is more of a metaphysics (metascience?) or philosophy issue.

Comment: Any science that deals with abstract objects is part of philosophy while remaining sciences are part of physics )))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not. Computer science has as much to do with computers as astronomy does with telescopes: they're a tool.

Even if computers didn't exist the science of computing things still would. IMO Computing Science would be a much better name, but we're stuck with what we have I guess.

Comment: Thanks. Is it a branch of math, then? Or is it a separate discipline in its own right?

Comment: @Thomas You could see it as a branch of mathematics if you must.

Comment: My professor always said that computer science is math with a bunch of energy consuming sand

Comment: @Thomas, it's better to see it as an interdisciplinary subject which straddles at least mathematics, engineering, and psychology.